# SimpleDateFormat Error

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a date in java, but I am missing something. After spent several hours in this I couldn't figure out the solution:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date2 =  formatter2.parse("09-Feb-13");  // throws error!
System.out.println(date2);
```

Comment: What is the error you're referring to?

Comment: Unparseable date: "09-Feb-13". Line 2

Comment: should it be "dd-MMM-yy" or "dd-MM-yy" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide a `Locale` to the formatter, it uses your default one which apparently doesn't spell months in English.

> `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)`
>
> Constructs a new`SimpleDateFormat`using the specified non-localized
>   pattern and the`DateFormatSymbols`and`Calendar`for the user's default
>   locale.

Specify one that does :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.UK);
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The date-time parsing/formatting types (the legacy, `SimpleDateFormat` and the modern, `DateTimeFormatter`) are `Locale`-sensitive. Your date string, `09-Feb-13` is in English and therefore, if you try to parse it on a JVM which has a non-English `Locale` set, your code will end up throwing an exception or giving you a wrong result (`SimpleDateFormat` is notorious in this regard for silently parsing/formatting erroneous data with wrong results).

Since the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone, it is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("09-Feb-13", dtf);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-02-09
```

In case you need an object of `java.util.Date`, you can get the same from this object of `LocalDate` as shown below:

```
Date utilDate = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>